# OpenGL FBO does not render to texture (C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, fbo

I have been trying to render a teapot to a FBO and then use the subsequent texture as a texture map. nothing seems to come up, so I was wondering what I was doing wrong. Below is the main loop:

```
//switch to fbo
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0.0,0.0,5.0, 
          0.0,0.0,-1.0,
          0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lpos);
glRotatef(a,0,1,1);
glutSolidTeapot(1);

   //switch to main

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0.0,0.0,5.0, 
          0.0,0.0,-1.0,
          0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, img);


   //draw cube

glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    // front faces
    glNormal3f(0,0,1);
    // face v0-v1-v2
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);  glVertex3f(1,1,1);
    glTexCoord2f(0,1);  glVertex3f(-1,1,1);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);  glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);
  ...draws cube
```

I have tried using the glFramebufferStatus and it has returned "success"

```
   glGenTextures(1, &img); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, img); 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glGenFramebuffers(1,&fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fbo);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthbuffer);    
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 512, 512);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthbuffer);

glGenTextures(1, &img); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, img); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 512, 512, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, img, 0);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);


GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

if (status==GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    printf("success\n");
}
```

However, all I get is the cube with no texture mapping.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible errors here:

1. Rendering into the FBO fails. To check if this is the case, clear the FBO with a distinct background color (e.g. pink) and see if the texture is affected (by reading it back to the CPU, for example). You should also make sure that your transformation matrices and the viewport (`glViewport`) are correct.
2. Texture mapping fails. Make sure that you've got everything set up for texture mapping and test texture mapping with a static texture first.

Comment: Good troubleshooting steps.  I think I'd test texture mapping first though, since knowing that works makes inspecting texture content more straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these steps tomorrow. In the case of 1, why would rendering int the FBO fail if the FBO is 'complete'?

Comment: As already mentioned, the viewport and transformation matrices might be unsuitable for your FBO resolution. I am not assuming the FBO is broken, rather that your way of rendering into it is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

What about `glEnable ( GL_TEXTURE_2D )` ?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled GL_TEXTURE_2D during the initialization